# Plot the means of multiple columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, summary, facet-wrap

I want to show **different barplots** for the **years** and **gender** with the **mean values of the variables Q1 to Q5**, which should look like a density.

I have data that looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(userid = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                  year = c(2013,2014,2015,2013,2014,2015,2013,2014,2015),
                  gender = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                  Q1 = c(3,2,3,1,0,1,2,1,0),
                  Q2 = c(4,3,4,2,0,2,1,4,3),
                  Q3 = c(1,2,1,3,5,4,5,4,5),
                  Q4 = c(1,2,1,2,4,3,2,2,1),
                  Q5 = c(1,1,1,2,1,0,0,0,1))
```

My solution was to `filter()` for year and gender first and then use `summarise()`,
to get a vector of the means and put this into the `barplot()` function:

```
data %>% filter(gender==1,year==2013) %>% select(-userid,-gender,-year) %>% summarise_all(mean) %>%
  as.numeric() %>%
  barplot()
```

Instead of doing this for every combination of year and gender,
is there a more elegant way, using ggplot and `facet_wrap()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have misunderstood how you want the plot arranged, but if you want to show the mean score answer per year and gender group, you could do facets like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Q")) %>%
  group_by(year, gender, name) %>%
  summarize(value = mean(value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value)) +
  geom_col(fill = 'deepskyblue4') +
  facet_grid(year ~ gender) +
  labs(x = 'Question', y = 'Average score') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this with `facet_wrap` and `geom_col` where the mean is calculate using `rowMeans` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data %>% 
  mutate(mean = rowMeans(select(., starts_with("Q")), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = mean, fill = factor(gender))) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(x = 'Year', y = 'Mean Q1 to Q5', fill = 'Gender') +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~userid)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

First, pivot your data from wide to long format, group by `year`, `gender`, and `Q`, and summarize to mean values.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data_long <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(Q1:Q5, names_to = "Q", values_to = "value") %>%
  group_by(year, gender, Q) %>%
  summarize(value = mean(value), .groups = "drop") 

data_long
```

```
# A tibble: 30 × 4
    year gender Q     value
   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1  2013      0 Q1      1.5
 2  2013      0 Q2      1.5
 3  2013      0 Q3      4  
 4  2013      0 Q4      2  
 5  2013      0 Q5      1  
 6  2013      1 Q1      3  
 7  2013      1 Q2      4  
 8  2013      1 Q3      1  
 9  2013      1 Q4      1  
10  2013      1 Q5      1  
# … with 20 more rows
```

Then plot using `ggplot2::facet_grid()`.

```
ggplot(data_long, aes(Q, value)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(year ~ gender)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`aggregate` then `barplot`.

```
par(mfrow=c(1, 4))
sapply(unique(data$year), \(x) {
  as.matrix(aggregate(cbind(Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5) ~ gender, data[data$year == x, ], FUN=mean)[-1]) |>
    barplot(beside=TRUE, col=c(2, 4), main=x)
})
plot.new()
legend('left', legend=c('m', 'f'), col=c(2, 4), cex=1.2, pch=15, bty='n')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This approach does not require you to first calculate the mean, that is handled by `stat_summary()`, specifying `fun = mean`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(userid = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                   year = c(2013,2014,2015,2013,2014,2015,2013,2014,2015),
                   gender = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                   Q1 = c(3,2,3,1,0,1,2,1,0),
                   Q2 = c(4,3,4,2,0,2,1,4,3),
                   Q3 = c(1,2,1,3,5,4,5,4,5),
                   Q4 = c(1,2,1,2,4,3,2,2,1),
                   Q5 = c(1,1,1,2,1,0,0,0,1))

data %>% 
  select(starts_with("Q")) %>% # Selects each column that starts with "Q"
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% # Pivot to long format
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = name)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun = "mean") + # Geom and function can be changed easily
  theme_classic() +
  labs(x = "Q", y = "Mean value", fill = NULL)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>